# Is there an easy way to transform a string to a mathematical expression with vbscript?

Tags: string, vbscript, operators

For example suppose I have

```
var1 = "15+28*3+(15.2+2)*2"
```

I want to return something like

```
var2 = CDbl(var1) or var2 = 133.4
```

Which I know it is wrong. But I am wondering if there is an easy solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Eval](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0z5x4094%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) to evaluate an expression:

```
>> s = "15+28*3+(15.2+2)*2"
>> WScript.Echo Eval(s)
>>
133,4
```

Comment: Thanks. I didnt't try this I thought it was only in VBA!